# Spring Data Jpa One To One mapping with where clause

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have two tables and I need OneToOne mapping with where clause.

```
select * from person_details inner join address_details
on address_details.pid=person_details.pid AND person_details.exist_flag = 'Y' AND address_details.address_exist_flag = 'Y'
```

Table 1

```
public class PersonDetails {
    @Id
    private String pid;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "exist_flag")
    private String existFlag;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "personDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Where(clause = "addressExistFlag = 'Y'")
    private AddressDetails addressDetails;
}
```

Table 2

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "address_details")
public class AddressDetails {
    @Id
    private String pid;

    private String street;

    @Column(name = "address_exist_flag")
    private String addressExistFlag;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private PersonDetails personDetails;

}
```

I need data to be fetched if both addressExistFlag = 'Y' and existFlag = 'Y'.

With current scenario If I am trying to fetch data via spring batch read repository as below, only existFlag = 'Y' is considered. **Is it because of incorrect mapping or the way I have used in spring batch**

ReadRepository looks like below

```
public interface PersonDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonDetails, String> {
    Page<PersonDetails> findByExistFlag(String existFlag, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Spring batch read repository looks like below

```
@Bean
RepositoryItemReader<PersonDetails> personDetailsItemReader() {
    Map<String, Sort.Direction> sort = new HashMap<>();
    sort.put("ExistFlag", Sort.Direction.ASC);
    return new RepositoryItemReaderBuilder<PersonDetails>()
            .repository(personDetailsRepository)
            .methodName("findByExistFlag")
            .arguments("Y")
            .sorts(sort)
            .name("personDetailsItemReader")
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only querying for existsFlag.

You have to add the other Flag too:

```
public interface PersonDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonDetails, String> {
    Page<PersonDetails> findByExistFlagAndAddressDetailsAddressExistFlag(
                        String existFlag, String addressExistFlag, Pageable pageable);
}


@Bean
RepositoryItemReader<PersonDetails> personDetailsItemReader() {
    Map<String, Sort.Direction> sort = new HashMap<>();
    sort.put("ExistFlag", Sort.Direction.ASC);
    return new RepositoryItemReaderBuilder<PersonDetails>()
            .repository(personDetailsRepository)
            .methodName("findByExistFlagAndAddressDetailsAddressExistFlag")
            .arguments("Y", "Y")
            .sorts(sort)
            .name("personDetailsItemReader")
            .build();
}
```

Comment: when does this clause will come into picture if I have to modify my repository method.@Where(clause = "addressExistFlag = 'Y'")

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: I mean to say where clause mentioned below in entity class will not be used while pulling data from DB with OneToOne mapping.                                                       @OneToOne(mappedBy = "personDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Where(clause = "addressExistFlag = 'Y'")
    private AddressDetails addressDetails;

Comment: This will be used to restrict the content of the collection but has nothing to do with the query

Comment: Would it could into picture If I call PersonDetailsRepository.findAll()

Comment: No the SQL statement is no affected